Cumulative sum with 2 date ranges
I need some help with a cumulative sum based on 2 date ranges please.
When a booking is requested - date requested (date 1)
When the booking is filled - date filled (date 2)
I would like the cumulative sum of when the booking is filled but still showing when it was requested.
I managed to use this formula to calculate it based on date filled.
Cumulative Count (Date Filled) = 
CALCULATE(
    [Total Bookings],
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(Table),
        Table[Date Filled] <= MAX (Table[Date Filled])
    )
)


However, when I add on the date requested in to show which month it was requested from, the cumulative sum is not showing correctly.

2nd line should accumulate to 3
4th line to 4
5th line to 5
6th line to 8 etc.
I hope the above makes sense. Thank you in advance for your help :).

Can you give the filled booking column dax query?
